# djangoでwordpressを使うのは不自然ですか？

Tags: python, wordpress, django

サービスを開発したいのですが、djangoでwpを動かすのは変ですか？

phpが書けないので、pythonでdjango使ってログイン認証などを作り、コンテンツの管理はWPの方が良いかと思いました。

またdjangoのCMSもそこまで良さげではないので困っています。
ご回答お願いします。

Answer (score 1):

WPとdjangoのやり取りをどうするかは、PHPが書けないということであれば、WPのプラグインを使うという方法、WPのREST APIを使う、WPが使っているデータベースをdjangoで書き換えるという方法等があります。

まず、認証ですがdjangoで、OAuth 2.0 の認証サーバーを作成して、WP側でOAuth 2.0用のプラグインを使えば認証ができるようになります。また、認証サーバーについては、djangoで作らなくても、Amazon CognitoやFirebase Authenticationのようなパブリッククラウドの認証機能を使ったほうが楽だと思います

それで、有料記事は会員のみみれるというようなサービスを作りたいのであれば、`pay.jp`等を使ったサプスクリプションや料金の管理する部分のアプリケーションはdjangoで作成し、それをWPのユーザー管理と連動してやればいいことになります。

WPのユーザー管理については、REST APIも使えるし、また、ユーザー管理用のプラグインもたくさんあるので、調べれば適当な方法がみつかると思います。

Comment: お返事ありがとうございます。初学者ですがサービスを作ることになり、苦戦しています。コンテンツのみWPで管理してアプリケーションはDjangoにしたいのですが、この場合pay.jpなど利用したサブスクリプションサービスつくれますか。Newspicksのようなモデルを作りたいです。有料記事は会員のみみれる、のような感じです。　変な質問ですみません。

Comment: WPにREST APIがあるのを忘れていました。それらを活用すれば、コメントにあるようなサービスであれば作れると思います。